# Firebase multiple browser tab authenticate

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am using `angularFireAuth` and angularFireAuth provides a logged in user variables. Let say `$scope.user.id` and I use this to verify if the current user logged. And also I use `angularFireAuth.logout()` to logout user.

Everything work fine on a single open browser tab.

But it doesn't work on multiple tabs.

- Login 1 of the tab `WILL NOT` login the other tabs and set the logged-in `variables`
- Logout 1 of the tab `DOES NOT` clear the other tabs `variables` and logout.

So it means

I opened 2 tabs, I call it **tab A** and **tab B**. When I logout or login in **tab A**.

**Tab B** will not do neither. In the sametime, if I submit something required authenticated in **tab b** (which tab A already logged out). I still able to submit. (unless I manually do refresh).

Comment: Are you calling angularFireAuth.logout() to implement logout?

Comment: @Anant yes.  when I login and logout. The authenticated `var` and session only work on single tab.

Comment: @Anant I updated my question to more clear

Comment: @vzhen Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the browser when you return to the second tab the authentication stored in local storage should update.

You can also leverage the local storage event to share events with other tabs and windows on the same domain. In the case of firebase, the user should automatically be updated within local storage, and kick off an event.

Listen for the storage change event then use firebase getAuth or the API that calls getAuth in angularFireAuth.

Could look like:

```
function onStorageEvent(storageEvent){
    var authData = ref.getAuth();
    if (authData !== null) {
       // you're logged in
    }
}
```

To be safe a messaging protocol that allows you to specify the action or event that should be handled can be implimented to use the local storage (You will recieve an event everytime storage state changes, ensure to have a message field in storage you can update and only complete actions on the other tabs based on events that update that message array, more safety should be involved here as well).

Shared storage messaging should only be required in case user was previously logged out, and it is intended that, all browser tabs open should change to logged in state when the login is completed in a different tab. Once logged in, all firebase events over websocket recieved by TabA should also be recieved by TabB, so that intertab communication would not be required.

Comment: It looks like you've lost a few logins, as is evident from this edit suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15183563. If you want to ask for a merger then please use the [contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) page and ask for an account merger.